# Сортировка массивов и запись в файл

Tags: c++

помогите разобраться с сортировкой и выводом всего этого в файл по возрастанию, пробовал реализовывать через динамические массивы, но так и не вышло..

Программа должна записывать значения из cin >> number в number.txt и сортировать их по возрастанию.

Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main () 
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int number;
    int *p_darr = new int[100000];
    ofstream fp("number.txt"); 

    do {
        cout << "Программа запишет целые числа в текстовый документ\n";
        cout << "Для выхода из программы вместо числа напишите 0\n";
        cout << "Введите целое число: ";
        cin >> number;
        fp << number;
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            p_darr[i] = i;
        }
        if(cin.good()) 
        { 
            cin.ignore(10, '\n');       
        } 

    } 
    while (number != 0);
        fp.close();
        delete [] p_darr;
        cout << "\033[1;31mКоманда для завершения работы принята.\033[0m\n";
        cout << "\033[1;31mРезультат записан в number.txt.\033[0m\n";
}
```

Comment: А в чём вопрос? Как написать сортировку?

Comment: Да, хотелось бы увидеть ответ с примером того, как это правильно реализовать.

Comment: Может быть вы приведёте пример как сами пытались реализовать, хотябы алгоритмом пузырка: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сортировать файл нельзя, сначала надо отсортировать массив, а затем уже записывать отсортированный в фай.
Простейшая сортировка - пузырьком: [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC)

Функция сортировки:

```
void BubbleSort(int *arr, int N){
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
         if (arr[j] < arr[i]){
             int tmp = arr[i];
             arr[i] = arr[j];
             arr[j] = tmp;
          }
       }
}
```

Вызываете как:

```
BubbleSort(p_darr, number);
```

Где number - размер массива.
Так же у вас массив заполняется просто числами от 0 до number. Если хотите считать данные из консоли то не `p_darr[i] = i;`, а `cin >> p_darr;`.
После сортировки просто выводите в файл как

```
for(int i = 0; i < number; ++i){
   fp << p_darr[i] << ' ';
}
```

И так как массив динамический, а размер вводите из консоли, то нет смысла выделять такой большой объём памяти, после считывания `cin >> number;` выделите массив размером `p_darr = new int[number];`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void BubbleSort(int *arr, int N){
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++){
         if (arr[j] < arr[i]){
             int tmp = arr[i];
             arr[i] = arr[j];
             arr[j] = tmp;
          }
       }
}

int main () 
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int number;
    int *p_darr;
    ofstream fp("number.txt"); 
    cout << "Программа запишет целые числа в текстовый документ\n";
    cout << "Для выхода из программы вместо числа напишите 0\n";
    cout << "Введите целое число: ";
    cin >> number;
    p_darr = new int[number];
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        cin >> p_darr[i];
    }
    BubbleSort(p_darr, number);   
    for(int i = 0; i < number; ++i){
       fp << p_darr[i] << ' ';
    }
    fp.close();
    delete [] p_darr;
    cout << "\033[1;31mКоманда для завершения работы принята.\033[0m\n";
    cout << "\033[1;31mРезультат записан в number.txt.\033[0m\n";
}
```

Comment: Не могли-бы вы помочь это объединить и сделать в моем коде, а то я не совсем понимаю куда вставлять.

Comment: Добавил в ответ.